# Why doesn't my toast work?

Tags: android, toast

Well basically, I can't get my toast to appear on screen in my application, I have copied the toast code into a different app and the code works fine, just for some reason I can't seem to get it to work in this one. I have stripped my application back to just the splash screen that doesnt do anything but call the toast in the onCreate method but still nothing. I have tried everything I can think of. Could someone please tell me whats wrong with it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class Splash extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 

        Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(this, "hello world", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t1.show();

    }//end onCreate     
} // end splash
```

The manifest is given below in case that is useful to anyone, the extra activities are launched from the main menu but ive cut the intent that starts the main menu out of the splash acitivity to try and make it simpler to figure out whats wrong

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.bluetoothdms"
     android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:largeHeap="true">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.bluetoothdms.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.bluetoothdms.MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.bluetoothdms.Bluetooth_Content"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.bluetoothdms.DMS_Content"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.bluetoothdms.FAQ"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.bluetoothdms.File_Opener">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Broken toaster?

Comment: Can you make a toast within the `onCreate` since it is not yet in the visible stage of the app/fragment lifecycle?

Comment: yes you can tronic because I called a toast in the oncreate of another app and it worked fine, i put it there to make it simpler, it doesnt work in on click methods or anywhere else i put it in this app either

Comment: Hmm... intriguing. For me works... with the EXACT syntax as you used. This looks like an Eclipse issue. Try a Project -> Clean

Comment: just tried it and nothing, is it possible the manifest or xml layout file could be blocking the toast?

Comment: post the manifest, the layout and let's take a look

Comment: When you add a Log.v, does it show in the LogCat?

Comment: mkay... nothing wrong with the manifest... how about your splash_layout?

Comment: thanks sebster, i dont think its the layout either, i emptied the layout and the issue still occured, I have also noticed that when I do a system.out.println("hello") nothing appears in logcat either

Comment: not it doesnt D-32, do you know what it might be?

Answer (score 0):

instantiate `Toast` with

```
Toast t1 = new Toast(context);
t1.makeText(....);
t1.show()
```

or use

```
Toast.makeText(...).show();
```

Comment: tried both ways you described already and nothing, ive tried everything